# Replace python numpy matrix value based on a condition, without using a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a symetric numpy matrix, for example.

```
matrix([[0.   , 0.125, 0.75 , 0.   , 0.   ],
        [0.125, 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
        [0.75 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.375],
        [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 1.2  ],
        [0.   , 0.   , 0.375, 1.2  , 0.   ]])
```

If a value in the array is greater than zero, is it possible to replace that value with the multiplication of the sum of that given row and column. For example 0.125 would be replaced by 0.109375, as row_sum * col_sum = 0.125 *(0.125+0.75)=0.109375.

I know it can be done using for loop, but is it possible to do using standard numpy library as I want to avoid for loops.

Comment: How about? np. matmul(np.ones(matrix.shape), matrix) * np.matmul(matrix, np.ones(matrix.shape))

Answer (score 2):

Declaring the given matrix

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.array([[0.   , 0.125, 0.75 , 0.   , 0.   ],
            [0.125, 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
            [0.75 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.375],
            [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 1.2  ],
            [0.   , 0.   , 0.375, 1.2  , 0.   ]])
```

using list comprehension and np.argwhere for conditional indices:

```
def replace(x,y,arr=arr,column_sums=arr.sum(axis=0),row_sum=arr.sum(axis=1)):
    arr[x][y]=row_sum[x]*column_sums[y]

_=[replace(x,y) for x,y in np.argwhere(arr>0)]
```

The output:

```
array([[0.      , 0.109375, 0.984375, 0.      , 0.      ],
       [0.109375, 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ],
       [0.984375, 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 1.771875],
       [0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 1.89    ],
       [0.      , 0.      , 1.771875, 1.89    , 0.      ]])
```

**Note that the code can be more optimized its laid out for better understanding**

Answer (score 0):

What about using numpy's indexing features?

```
arr[arr > 0] = x
```

Comment: How would I then custom reference each indexed element to its given row and col to get the relevant sum?